# Performance of F# code terrible

Tags: performance, recursion, f#, sequences

This is my very first F# programme.  I thought I would implement Conway's Game of Life as a first exercise.

Please help me understand why the following code has such terrible performance.

```
let GetNeighbours (p : int, w : int, h : int) : seq<int> =
    let (f1, f2, f3, f4) = (p > w, p % w <> 1, p % w <> 0, p < w * (h - 1))
    [
    (p - w - 1, f1 && f2);
    (p - w, f1);
    (p - w + 1, f1 && f3);
    (p - 1, f2);
    (p + 1, f3);
    (p + w - 1, f4 && f2);
    (p + w, f4);
    (p + w + 1, f4 && f3)
    ]
    |> List.filter (fun (s, t) -> t)
    |> List.map (fun (s, t) -> s)
    |> Seq.cast

let rec Evolve (B : seq<int>, S : seq<int>, CC : seq<int>, g : int) : unit =
    let w = 10
    let h = 10
    let OutputStr = (sprintf "Generation %d:  %A" g CC) // LINE_MARKER_1
    printfn "%s" OutputStr
    let CCN = CC |> Seq.map (fun s -> (s, GetNeighbours (s, w, h)))
    let Survivors =
        CCN
        |> Seq.map (fun (s, t) -> (s, t |> Seq.map (fun u -> (CC |> Seq.exists (fun v -> u = v)))))
        |> Seq.map (fun (s, t) -> (s, t |> Seq.filter (fun u -> u)))
        |> Seq.map (fun (s, t) -> (s, Seq.length t))
        |> Seq.filter (fun (s, t) -> (S |> Seq.exists (fun u -> t = u)))
        |> Seq.map (fun (s, t) -> s)
    let NewBorns =
        CCN
        |> Seq.map (fun (s, t) -> t)
        |> Seq.concat
        |> Seq.filter (fun s -> not (CC |> Seq.exists (fun t -> t = s)))
        |> Seq.groupBy (fun s -> s)
        |> Seq.map (fun (s, t) -> (s, Seq.length t))
        |> Seq.filter (fun (s, t) -> B |> Seq.exists (fun u -> u = t))
        |> Seq.map (fun (s, t) -> s)
    let NC = Seq.append Survivors NewBorns
    let SWt = new System.Threading.SpinWait ()
    SWt.SpinOnce ()
    if System.Console.KeyAvailable then
        match (System.Console.ReadKey ()).Key with
        | System.ConsoleKey.Q -> ()
        | _ -> Evolve (B, S, NC, (g + 1))
    else 
        Evolve (B, S, NC, (g + 1))

let B = [3]
let S = [2; 3]
let IC = [4; 13; 14]
let g = 0
Evolve (B, S, IC, g)
```

The first five iterations, i.e. generations 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, happen without a problem.  Then, after a brief pause of about 100 milliseconds, generation 5 is completed.  But after that, the programme hangs at the line marked "LINE_MARKER_1," as revealed by breakpoints Visual Studio.  It never reaches the `printfn` line.

The strange thing is, already by generation 2, the `CC` sequence in the function `Evolve` has already stabilised to the sequence `[4; 13; 14; 3]` so I see no reason why generation 6 should fail to evolve.

I understand that it is generally considered opprobrious to paste large segments of code and ask for help in debugging, but I don't know how to reduce this to a minimum working example.  Any pointers that would help me debug would be gratefully acknowledged.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

I really believe that anyone wishing to help me may pretty much ignore the `GetNeighbours` function.  I included it only for the sake of completeness.

Comment: So should I re-write the whole thing with lists?  In your opinion, would that solve the problem?

Comment: Is there any documentation on why Seq would lead to such bad performance?  I have read the MSDN pages on F#'s sequences, but I didn't come across anything particularly alarming.

Comment: @Shredderroy : `Seq` is for lazy evaluation, which you almost certainly do not want.

Comment: F# sequence doesn't give decent performance. Using `Seq.length` and `Seq.append` makes performance even worse.

Comment: Also - note that you don't need `Seq.cast` (it doesn't do what you think it does). Replacing `|> Seq.cast` with `:> _` does what you want, and yet keeps the types checked. You can also not cast to `seq` at all.

Comment: Switching to lists speeds this up incredibly. There are other optimisations I see (for example, composing the `map`s, perhaps even joining them to the `filter`s using `choose`) - but switching to lists solves most of the problem (I left the `Seq.groupBy id`, but added `List.ofSeq` after it).

Comment: @pad, cannot agree with you - Seq, when used appropriately, performs well and in some situations is preferable to lists or arrays.

Comment: @ildjarn, correct that Seq does not immediately compute the arguments, however I would say that it is not lazy by default since it is prone to recompute (unlike Haskell lazy lists).

Comment: @RamonSnir, small optimizations are great, however the real elephant in the room is the `O(exp(N))` complexity the user has inadvertently programmed by using `Seq` incorrectly.

Comment: @toyvo ideally, you are correct - but the coefficients are small (relatively to his computing resources) and his demands are not very high. If you'll run the code with `Seq` and with `List`, you will see (that the example he gave is a bit static and non-generic but also) that the `List` module solves the major issue for this case.

Comment: @RamonSnir Yes, `List` is one way to solve `O(exp(N))`. However I think the bigger problem is not understanding Seq. "Never use Seq" is not very educational as far as advice goes :)

Comment: @Shredderroy: Arrays are going to perform better than `Seq`s and even lists for this kind of processing because of locality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See comments and all, but this code runs like hell - with both `List.*` and some other smaller optimisations:

```
let GetNeighbours p w h =
    let (f1, f2, f3, f4) = p > w, p % w <> 1, p % w <> 0, p < w * (h - 1)
    [
        p - w - 1, f1 && f2
        p - w, f1
        p - w + 1, f1 && f3
        p - 1, f2
        p + 1, f3
        p + w - 1, f4 && f2
        p + w, f4
        p + w + 1, f4 && f3
    ]
    |> List.choose (fun (s, t) -> if t then Some s else None)

let rec Evolve B S CC g =
    let w = 10
    let h = 10
    let OutputStr = sprintf "Generation %d:  %A" g CC // LINE_MARKER_1
    printfn "%s" OutputStr
    let CCN = CC |> List.map (fun s -> s, GetNeighbours s w h)
    let Survivors =
        CCN
        |> List.choose (fun (s, t) ->
            let t =
                t
                |> List.filter (fun u -> CC |> List.exists ((=) u))
                |> List.length
            if S |> List.exists ((=) t) then
                Some s
            else None)
    let NewBorns =
        CCN
        |> List.collect snd
        |> List.filter (not << fun s -> CC |> List.exists ((=) s))
        |> Seq.countBy id
        |> List.ofSeq
        |> List.choose (fun (s, t) ->
            if B |> List.exists ((=) t) then
                Some s
            else None)
    let NC = List.append Survivors NewBorns
    let SWt = new System.Threading.SpinWait()
    SWt.SpinOnce()
    if System.Console.KeyAvailable then
        match (System.Console.ReadKey()).Key with
        | System.ConsoleKey.Q -> ()
        | _ -> Evolve B S NC (g + 1)
    else 
        Evolve B S NC (g + 1)

let B = [3]
let S = [2; 3]
let IC = [4; 13; 14]
let g = 0
Evolve B S IC g
```

Comment: I would use `Seq.countBy` instead of `Seq.groupBy` here.

Comment: You can cut the run time in half by switching to arrays.

Comment: @Daniel arrays indeed seem to be faster.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to fix your performance is by using `Seq.cache`:

```
let GetNeighbours (p : int, w : int, h : int) : seq<int> =
    let (f1, f2, f3, f4) = (p > w, p % w <> 1, p % w <> 0, p < w * (h - 1))
    [
    (p - w - 1, f1 && f2);
    (p - w, f1);
    (p - w + 1, f1 && f3);
    (p - 1, f2);
    (p + 1, f3);
    (p + w - 1, f4 && f2);
    (p + w, f4);
    (p + w + 1, f4 && f3)
    ]
    |> List.filter (fun (s, t) -> t)
    |> List.map (fun (s, t) -> s)
    :> seq<_> // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< MINOR EDIT, avoid boxing

let rec Evolve (B : seq<int>, S : seq<int>, CC : seq<int>, g : int) : unit =
    let w = 10
    let h = 10
    let OutputStr = (sprintf "Generation %d:  %A" g CC) // LINE_MARKER_1
    printfn "%s" OutputStr
    let CCN =
        CC
        |> Seq.map (fun s -> (s, GetNeighbours (s, w, h)))
        |> Seq.cache // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< EDIT
    let Survivors =
        CCN
        |> Seq.map (fun (s, t) -> (s, t |> Seq.map (fun u -> (CC |> Seq.exists (fun v -> u = v)))))
        |> Seq.map (fun (s, t) -> (s, t |> Seq.filter (fun u -> u)))
        |> Seq.map (fun (s, t) -> (s, Seq.length t))
        |> Seq.filter (fun (s, t) -> (S |> Seq.exists (fun u -> t = u)))
        |> Seq.map (fun (s, t) -> s)
    let NewBorns =
        CCN
        |> Seq.map (fun (s, t) -> t)
        |> Seq.concat
        |> Seq.filter (fun s -> not (CC |> Seq.exists (fun t -> t = s)))
        |> Seq.groupBy (fun s -> s)
        |> Seq.map (fun (s, t) -> (s, Seq.length t))
        |> Seq.filter (fun (s, t) -> B |> Seq.exists (fun u -> u = t))
        |> Seq.map (fun (s, t) -> s)
    let NC =
        Seq.append Survivors NewBorns
        |> Seq.cache // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< EDIT
    let SWt = new System.Threading.SpinWait ()
    SWt.SpinOnce ()
    if System.Console.KeyAvailable then
        match (System.Console.ReadKey ()).Key with
        | System.ConsoleKey.Q -> ()
        | _ -> Evolve (B, S, NC, (g + 1))
    else
        Evolve (B, S, NC, (g + 1))

let B = [3]
let S = [2; 3]
let IC = [4; 13; 14]
let g = 0
Evolve (B, S, IC, g)
```

The big problem is not using `Seq` per se, the problem is using it correctly. By default sequences are not lazy, instead they define computations that are re-evaluated on every traversal. This means that unless you do something about it (such as `Seq.cache`), re-evaluating the sequence may screw up the algorithmic complexity of your program.

Your original program has exponential complexity. To see that, note that it doubles the number of traversed elements with each iteration.

Also note that with your style of programming using `Seq` operators followed by `Seq.cache` has a small advantage over using `List` or `Array` operators: this avoids allocating intermediate data structures, which reduces GC pressure and may speed things up a bit.

Comment: Excellent!  With these two small edits, I get 10,000 evolutions in 11428 milliseconds.  This is slightly faster than the the version with lists, which requires 12719 milliseconds for 10,000 evolutions.  Now I am going to try David's suggestion and use arrays.

Comment: I think it's really not about speed, it's about complexity. Your original code has poor algorithmic complexity. All suggested solutions have the same complexity - timing differences do not matter for your use case (and most use cases).

Answer (score 3):

Just thought I would add a simple answer, in case other beginners like me run into the same problem.

As advised by `Ramon Snir`, `ildjarn` and `pad` above, I changed the `Seq.X` calls to `List.X`.  I had to add a simple extra casting step to account for the fact that `List` does not have `groupBy`, but having done that, the code now runs like a charm!

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most amazing characteristics of the ML family of languages is that short code is often fast code and this applies to F# too.

Compare your implementation with the much faster one I blogged [here](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/john-conways-game-of-life-in-32-lines.html):

```
let count (a: _ [,]) x y =
  let m, n = a.GetLength 0, a.GetLength 1
  let mutable c = 0
  for x=x-1 to x+1 do
    for y=y-1 to y+1 do
      if x>=0 && x<m && y>=0 && y<n && a.[x, y] then
        c <- c + 1
  if a.[x, y] then c-1 else c

let rule (a: _ [,]) x y =
  match a.[x, y], count a x y with
  | true, (2 | 3) | false, 3 -> true
  | _ -> false
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing!  Yes, this is shorter and faster.  The only defence I can present is that my implementation separates the "board" from the evolution.  In my source code (not shown here) I have the following "boards":  "hard square" (square with truncation at the edges), cylinder, genus-1 torus, RP2.  I want to write a few other boards too, with interesting low dimension topology.  I'm always trying to see how to improve my code.

Comment: @Shredderroy I see. I was quite perplexed when I first saw your code but if it is designed to be generic over topologies then that makes sense. I did something similar during my PhD to study the effects of network topology on the simulation of amorphous materials.